# How JavaScript load HTMP page with its own JavaScript file in different folder? Keep getting Error GET http://localhost:x/f.js 404 (Not Found) why?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

In my JavaScript file that has name SPA.js, I am loading HTML page called MenuEditor.html with following location: wwwroot /HtmlTemp/MenuEditor.html [image: Problem description]

In MenuEditor.html I am trying to load JSmenuError.js that is in the same folder as the MenuEditor.html

I drag and drop the JSmenuError.js into MenuEditor.html

[image: Error]

I got Error GET http://localhost:xxx/file.js 404 (Not Found) in the chrome inspector.

[image: 404 (Not Found)]

What is the issue with the path?

Please note that the JSmenu.js file that in the same folder as my main SPA.js works OK when I drag it into the MenuEditor.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to always use paths starting at the root of your webserver, for example `/scripts/jsmenuerror.js`. Different webservers and browsers have treated going up a directory (`../`) differently over the years. I haven't used ASP.NET Core, but there should also be a helper available like `Url.Content` or `ResolveUrl` you could use.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer! So far I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl?view=netframework-4.8 . Could you please recommend some more information on Url.Content or ResolveUrl topic ?